# How to Create EventRelation using REST API

Tags: rest-api, contact, event

I'm trying to create an EventRelation using the REST API, but it does not seem to be working. Here are the details of the request:

**URI**: /services/data/v37.0/sobjects/EventRelation/

With the following in the body of the request:

**EventId**: xxx (ID of the event I want to add a relation to)

**RelationId**: xxx (ID of a specific contact)

The API doesn't create the EventRelation and just returns the following:

```
{
  "objectDescribe": {
    "activateable": false,
    "createable": true,
    "custom": false,
    "customSetting": false,
    "deletable": true,
    "deprecatedAndHidden": false,
    "feedEnabled": false,
    "keyPrefix": "0RE",
    "label": "Event Relation",
    "labelPlural": "Event Relations",
    "layoutable": false,
    "mergeable": false,
    "mruEnabled": false,
    "name": "EventRelation",
    "queryable": true,
    "replicateable": true,
    "retrieveable": true,
    "searchable": false,
    "triggerable": false,
    "undeletable": false,
    "updateable": true,
    "urls": {
      "rowTemplate": "/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/EventRelation/{ID}",
      "defaultValues": "/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/EventRelation/defaultValues?recordTypeId&fields",
      "describe": "/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/EventRelation/describe",
      "sobject": "/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/EventRelation"
    }
  },
  "recentItems": [
  ]
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Am I not passing required fields? I simply just want to attach a lead or contact to an event.

Comment: Are you setting the method as `POST` instead of `GET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you just specified `GET` instead of `POST` as the method. That returns the describe, instead of trying to create a record. **Make sure you set your method to `POST`.**

---

**POST**

Notice how the API is clearly trying to create a record here:

[image: POST Results]

---

**GET**

Here, the API returns the describe:

[image: GET Results]

Comment: Ah this makes so much sense thanks! I'm now getting the error "The HTTP entity body is required, but this request has no entity body." which is strange because I am passing the EventId and RelationId in the body, any thoughts?

Comment: @ChrisSchlitt I would create a new question for that and share the actual code you use to make the callout.